# Entity Framework dbset attach non-static method requires a target

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lazy-loading

I'm manually loading a DBSET from the EF, and the base mapping works. The error occurs when that same DBSET must be used for another query with lazy loading, it returns the error "non-static method requires a target", Example:

```
// class 1
public Transaction GetTx(int id){
    // load data to POCO with other source

    Transaction tx = new Transaction() { prop1 = 1, prop2 = "xx");
    ctx.Transactions.Attach(tx);
    return tx;
}

// class 2
public void OtherMethod(){
    Transaction tx = GetTx(1);
    // do something with tx

    // load with lazy loading
    var detail = context.Detail.Where(x => x.Service.Code == tx.Port.Service.Code).ToList(); // here occurs error "non-static method requires a target"
}
```

How can I manually load the DBSET and then continue the lazy loading of the other related tables?

EDIT 1:

I'm using load offline, because I'm having performance issues. I am migrating an old project with "Database First" to "Code First", the EF code is the same as always, but the mapping has changed (I am working with Oracle 10g). For some reason with DB First the query executes in less than 50ms, but with Code First it takes more than 3 seconds and is a critical service.

If I offline load the main table, it stays within 50ms. What could I change to have the same DB First performance with Code First, without having to change the logic?

PS: I use .Net 4.5.1, EF 6.2, Oracle 10g and I don't have many chances to update these features for a few months (company policies that I can't modify)

Comment: Is tx null? What about context?

Comment: Tx is not null, but tx.Port is null. If loaded in connected mode, lazy loading does its job and loads it right away, but using an offline object doesn't load it.

Comment: You'll need to troubleshoot the query on Oracle.

Comment: The strange thing is that the SQL queries are fast if I execute them in PLSQL DEVELOP, if I change in EF by manual query with the ".SqlQuery" method, the execution is fast, only by letting EF automatically generate its query is slow.

Comment: If I add an interceptor, I see that EF generates the same query as the manual query I use (it just adds more aliases)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use DbSet offline.  It requires a database connection.  In offline scenarios you can use the [Sqlite provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sqlite/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) or (for testing) the [in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/in-memory/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli).

Comment: Thank you David. I edited the question to give more context, I wanted to do this due to performance issues... what other alternative do I have to improve the performance of code first?